# Insert data to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, json, postgresql

Im inserting data to a PostgreSQL database using the below function.

Im not very happy with the solution for the `IF` statements to handle the adaptation of Python `None` to PostgreSQL `NULL`. Would there be a more elegant solution I would be happy yo know.

Also, I believe I am not being very performant using `.execute()` method .
Where could i start to convert my function to make usage of `.executemany()` perhaps.

```
def insert_into_table(data):
    # print json.dumps(data, indent=4)

    conn = psycopg2.connect(database='testdb', user='postgres', password='password', host='localhost')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    for i in data:
        # print json.dumps(i, indent=4)
        iso_code = i["iso_code"]

        if i["l_postcode"] is None:
            l_postcode = 'NULL'
        else:
            l_postcode = i["l_postcode"]

        if i["r_postcode"] is None:
            r_postcode = 'NULL'
        else:
            r_postcode = i["r_postcode"]
        link_id = i["link_id"]
        geom = i["geometry"]

        # sql = 'INSERT into data_load VALUES (\'{}\', {}, {},{} , st_geomfromgeojson(\'{}\'))'.format(iso_code, l_postcode, r_postcode, link_id, json.dumps(geom))
        sql = """INSERT into data_load (iso_code, l_postcode, r_postcode, link_id, geom) VALUES ('{}',{},{},{},st_geomfromgeojson(\'{}\'));""".format(iso_code, l_postcode, r_postcode, link_id, json.dumps(geom))
        print sql

        cursor.execute(sql, )
        print sql

    cursor.close()
    conn.commit()

    conn.close()
```

A json fragment example of the load im trying to load , this example has only 3 objects for the sake of simplicity .

```
[
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    -91.98979, 
                    15.644559999999998
                ], 
                [
                    -91.98971, 
                    15.645249999999999
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "iso_code": "MEX", 
        "l_postcode": null, 
        "r_postcode": null, 
        "link_id": 1186786776
    }, 
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    -106.77742, 
                    28.390159999999998
                ], 
                [
                    -106.77806, 
                    28.39076
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "iso_code": "MEX", 
        "l_postcode": null, 
        "r_postcode": null, 
        "link_id": 818231403
    }, 
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString", 
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    -98.89940999999999, 
                    18.90605
                ], 
                [
                    -98.89926, 
                    18.906689999999998
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        "iso_code": "MEX", 
        "l_postcode": null, 
        "r_postcode": null, 
        "link_id": 1130886811
    }
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Do not use string formatting to pass parameters to SQL queries.**

This way you are not only getting type conversion and quotes balancing/escaping issues, but also making your code vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Mandatory XKCD:

[image]

([source](https://xkcd.com/327/))

Instead, *parameterize your query* - put placeholders into the query and let your database driver worry about the Python to database type conversions.

In this case, you should be able to pass your `data` list of dictionaries directly to `executemany()` specifying dictionary-based query placeholders:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import Json


def insert_into_table(data):
    # preparing geometry json data for insertion
    for item in data:
        item['geom'] = Json(item['geometry'])

    with psycopg2.connect(database='testdb', user='postgres', password='password', host='localhost') as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            query = """
                INSERT into 
                    data_load 
                    (iso_code, l_postcode, r_postcode, link_id, geom) 
                VALUES 
                    (%(iso_code)s, %(l_postcode)s, %(r_postcode)s, %(link_id)s, st_geomfromgeojson(%(geom)s));
            """
            cursor.executemany(query, data)

        conn.commit()
```

Also note how I'm using `cursor` and `conn` as *context managers*.

Comment: Thanks alecxe . really appreciate the lesson. It makes all the sense much more clean and elegant as i was looking for ... unfortunaly there is something missing im getting a key error     cursor.executemany(query, data)
KeyError: 'geom' ... i suspect this is related to the postgis function beeing use 'st_geomfromgeojson'

Comment: @JorgeVidinha right, it should be `geometry`, fixed the placeholder, please try again. Thanks.

Comment: tried ... but     cursor.executemany(query, data)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

Comment: @JorgeVidinha yup, we need to dump the `geometry` to JSON - updated the code - should work now. Thanks!

Comment: still not there yet , do i still have credits -- cursor.executemany(query, data)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 6: ..., 23.722279999999998], [-103.97212, 23.723139999999997]]}');
                                                                      ^

Comment: @JorgeVidinha of course, let's solve this. What if you put single quotes around the `%(geom)s`? (apologies, have not used `st_geomfromgeojson()` before)

Comment: like -> st_geomfromgeojson('%(geom)s'); error is -> cursor.executemany(query, data)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 6: ...EX', NULL, NULL, 1121302534, st_geomfromgeojson(''{"type": "...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62156/discussion-between-alecxe-and-jorge-vidinha).